# Issue with "MembersWithData" property of Parent-Child hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

Assume Jack & Jill are two managers. Jack has one reportee called James and Jill has none. So when we establish Parent-Child relationship, Jack & Jill will be at Level 1 and James will be at Level 2. In our project all the 3 people make sales. Hence a manager like Jack will have his group sales and his own sales.

To represent it, i have set the property "MembersWithData = NonLeafDataVisible" for parent attribute. When  I browse the cube the data is represented something like this

Jack --- $100

- Jack (Direct)------$60
- James        ------$40

Jill ---- $200

We can clearly see that Jill doesn't have any children unlike Jack. It seems SSAS adding a member (in our case "Jack (Direct)") as its own children only when it really has some children.

What should I have to do if I want to have "Jill (Direct)"  under Jill, something like following.

Jack --- $100

- Jack (Direct)------$60
- James        ------$40

Jill ---- $200

- Jill (Direct)------$200